# If $f\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)=x$ then find $f(x)$

Tags: functions

If $f\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)=x$ then find $f(x)$

My attempt :-

Put $x= \tan^2(\theta)$

Then $f(\cos(2\theta))=\tan^2(\theta)$

After this ....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to know how $x$ varies in terms of $\frac{1-x}{1+x}.$ 
Thus, you need to find the inverse of $g(x) = \frac{1-x}{1+x}.$ 
Writing $$y = \frac{1-x}{1+x},$$
you can expand $x$ in terms of y. Then, you get $x = \frac{1-y}{1+y}$ which implies that $$f(y) = x = \frac{1-y}{1+y}$$ 
and using the symbol "$x$," you get 
$$f(x) = \frac{1-x}{1+x}$$

Comment: Explain it more

Comment: I added more details.

Answer (score 1):

Let $y=\cos2\theta \implies \theta=\frac 12 \cos^{-1}y$ and so $$f(y) = \tan^2\left(\frac 12\cos^{-1}y\right) $$

EDIT: A better method would be to start with $$f\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right) = x$$ and substitute $y=\frac{1-x}{1+x} \implies x=\frac{1-y}{1+y}$ and so $$f(y)=\frac{1-y}{1+y}$$

Comment: How I find f(x) from f(y)

Comment: @AbhishekKumar just replace $y$ by $x$.

Answer (score 1):

$$f\left( \frac{1-x}{1+x} \right)=x \implies f(z)=\left(\frac{1-z}{1+z}\right) \implies f(x)=\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right) $$

Answer (score 1):

You can backtrack the function because you know that $f\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)=x$
You can then see what operations can you perform to make $\frac{1-x}{1+x}$ to get $x$ then you will see
$$f(x)=2\left(\frac{1}{x+1}\right)-1$$
If you simplify this, you get the same function, that is
$$f(x)=\frac{1-x}{1+x}$$
If you input $\frac{1-x}{1+x}$ you get $x$

Answer (score 1):

For $x \neq -1$, Let us put 
$$
y \colon= \frac{1-x}{1+x}.
$$
Then we find that $y \neq -1$, and also that
$$
\frac{1-y}{1+y} = \frac{ 2x }{ 2 } = x,
$$
and thus
$$
f(x) = f \left( \frac{1-y}{1+y} \right) = y = \frac{1-x}{1+x}.
$$